# Idiomatic Go for handling any image type with any color type?

Tags: go, image-processing

I've found that when I decode images in Go I can get drastically different image types (`*image.RGBA`, `*image.CMYK`, `*image.Paletted`, and more) with conflicting color types (usually paired up to match the image type, e.g. `color.RGBA`, `color.CMYK`, `color.Palette`, etc). It's easy to write brittle code that handles an `*image.RGBA` perfectly every time, but then it'll panic if the code encounters any other type of image.

I could leave the decoded image as `image.Image` and use the `ColorModel` to ensure my colors are always in the right format but I would still need to know what the actual type of the image is to call `Set` and if it turns out the image was a paletted image, I may not have control over how the finished image looks. A lot of runtime stability can be gained if I can always convert an image into a specific known type before I do anything with it.

Is there an idiomatic Go approach to standardizing image types before doing whatever processing I want to do to them?

EDIT: [Another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535474/convert-image-from-image-ycbcr-to-image-rgba/47539710) details how to convert to a target image type but I'm unsure how "idiomatic" it is vs how "duct tape" it is. It lead me to write this:

```
func ConvertToRGBA(img image.Image) (rgba *image.RGBA) {
    var ok bool
    rgba, ok = img.(*image.RGBA)
    if ok {
        return rgba
    }

    b := img.Bounds()
    rgba = image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, b.Dx(), b.Dy()))
    draw.Draw(rgba, rgba.Bounds(), img, b.Min, draw.Src)

    return rgba
}
```

Is this as good as it gets or am I way off base?

Comment: RGB and CMYK are (in general anyway) not absolute color spaces (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space), hence to convert from one to another, you need two profiles. You may find that some inputs (in CMYK) are outside the gamut of your RGB space.

Comment: A) "A lot of runtime stability can be gained if I can always convert an image into a specific known type before I do anything with it." Correct for the wrong reason. "Runtime stability" is achieved by proper coding. But depending on _what_ you want to do exactly with an image you must _know_ the color space. Some things are easy in one color space some in an other. B) "Is there an idiomatic Go approach to standardizing image types before doing whatever processing I want to do to them?" No, because there is no single colorspace which fits all purposes equally well.