# Simple, effective GUI packages in GoLang

Tags: go, user-interface, package, shapes, draw

I am learning GoLang and trying to create a GUI or two for a school project.

I just need simple functionality like buttons attached to action listeners, a textbox, and a panel where I can draw shapes or points based on pixel coordinates.

So far I have seen this post about drawing shapes to PNG images:  [Draw a rectangle in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992396/draw-a-rectangle-in-golang)

but not how to draw the shapes on a GUI and update them.

Can anyone recommend a good GUI, straightforward package to use for GoLang?

N/A

this question does not involve tested input or output.

Comment: Asking for package recommendations is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here so your question is likely to be closed. You might find resources like [awesome-go](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#gui) and [go-gui-projects](https://github.com/go-graphics/go-gui-projects), or articles [like this](https://blog.logrocket.com/best-gui-frameworks-go/), helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can Try [Fyne](https://developer.fyne.io/started/)

It has components that you require